# lilypond scheme function optional argument

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

**How do I make an argument in a scheme function optional?**

[This](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/extending/scheme-function-definitions) says

> A Scheme type predicate for which argN must return #t. There is also a
> special form (predicate? default) for specifying optional arguments.

Unfortunately, this does not tell me what I need to write - at least not in a way I understand.

---

Here is my scheme function:

```
pageSong = 
#(define-scheme-function
   (title music stanzas)
   (string? ly:music? markup?)
      #{
        \bookpart { 
          \header {
            title = $title
          } 
          \score {
            $music
            \layout {}
          }
          $stanzas
        }
      #})
```

I want `stanzas` to be optional. How do I need to modify my code to achieve that?
I tried replacing `markup?` by `(predicate? default)`, but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An optional argument at the end of the argument list is not all that optional: the specified default is only used when you explicitly write `\default` in place of the "optional" argument in the call of the scheme function.

Usually you want optional arguments be recognised as being omitted because the specified predicate (in your case, `markup?`) does not fit what comes next.  So you'd want to use something like

```
pageSong = 
#(define-scheme-function
   (title stanzas music)
   (string? (markup? empty-markup) ly:music?)
      #{
        \bookpart { 
          \header {
            title = $title
          } 
          \score {
            $music
            \layout {}
          }
          $stanzas
        }
      #})
```

And then either write some markup for `stanzas` *before* the music or not.  In the latter case, since the music will usually not be in a form LilyPond can interpret as markup, LilyPond will then substitute empty-markup for the `stanzas`.

It's possible that you want a `markup-list?` instead (a single markup can never be broken across pages); in that case you'd use '() for the default empty markup list.